# How to overcome a class with too many dependencies in the constructor?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, constructor, facade

I have a Python project where I have a Car class that has a main state machine with multiple states. Moreover, The Car class has multiple systems. These systems are Engine, GearBox, Brakes, Dashboard, Stereo and a few more. During the transition of each state, I have entry and exit action which do something with these systems. But aside from this I should be able to control the systems separately as well by checking in which state I am at the moment.

As you can see I have multiple systems and passing them as a dependency injection to my Car class leads to constructor bloating which indicates too many responsibilities. This problem I need to solve.

I tried to solve this by moving similar systems behind a facade class but the issue I find here is that for some of the systems, the components that make these systems need to be controller separately as well. An example here:

We have a system that consists of 2 more systems. In the facade I can call a method activate system and that method will have the two systems behind this facade system be activated but sometimes I need to be able to activate them separately from each other. Now, I could just have 2 more methods activating each system separately in the facade class but that kind of feels to me that I am breaking the principle behind the facade pattern.

I guess in general I could explain my problem as such where I have a class that has many dependencies that are needed and I try to move them behind facades but after some facades there is more behaviour I need to call directly in the main class but then that makes my code really nested with multiple facades within facades.

Comment: How often are you calling the Car constructor though? If it is logical what are you doing (i.e. a card needs an engine, etc.) I would not mind that, especially with proper formatting. You could also add the individual parts via methods like `add_engine()`. But I am note sure if that would be much better than a longer constructor. You could also say that not the car has an engine, but an engine belongs to car and contrsuct your individual subsystems with a reference to the car that owns them.

Comment: Well, it will be ideally only created once and then call the car object methods whenever the frontend makes a request for an action - whether that is a state change or using any of the systems.

Comment: More code, less description of your code.

Comment: I, personally, would than accept that a car object has many dependencies in favor of the intuitive and natural ownership of the systems as part of a car.

Comment: The big problems is that the car has indeed many systems it can control and these systems have systems inside themselves. So I need to go quite a lot into nesting a system inside a system.

Comment: If you just have a complex system with many different parts then it is so and can be reflected in a large constructor. For Python especially it can be made look a bit nicer with e. g. a dict holding the subsystems and giving this dict to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you’ve landed in clean-code hell :) This “bloat” is typical when you try to inject everything. it’s so typical that there are objects that handle this injection, and they are called “dependency injectors” for the surprise of no one. See [this project](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/) for example.

I’d try to simplify, honestly. I wouldn’t inject absolutely everything, unless this is a project to learn about unit testing, abstractions or your professor/tech lead is really a purist.

Remember that premature abstraction (and optimization) is the root of all evil.

Comment: Well, wouldn't using such a container just be a workaround the problem of having too many dependencies? 

True that its a bit of a clean-code hell. The issue is that all the dependencies seem necessary for me, otherwise I can't use them inside my state machine.